# make api call only listen to localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express, mean-stack

I have an website which is constructed to use api calls in the same node project. I want the most of these api calls only be available to the localhost website.

Isn't there an option for not using oath and just listen to localhost?

Comment: In your API server, you can filter whether the source of the request is your local host IP or not and act accordingly.  You have to do this at the TCP level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put localhost with port where you write

```
app.listen(PORT_NUMBER,'localhost',function(){
   console.log('server started on '+PORT_NUMBER);
})
```

this will make your whole node server start listening on localhost:PORT_NUMBER but if you want to make certain routes to listen on localhost than you can place middleware over those calls to and write code in middleware to filterout all the calls which are not made from local. for example :-

```
    app.get('/first',function(req,res){
    })

    // middleware to filter calls
    app.use(function(req,res,next){
      var ipOfSource = request.connection.remoteAddress;
      if(ipOfSource == '127.0.0.1' || ipOfSource == 'localhost') next();
    })

   // all routes which need to be need to accessed from localhost goes here.
    app.get('/will be accessible from localhost',function(req,res){

    })
```